# Another rebus for your brain aerobics

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, rebus

This is a saying from an ancient book (a saying Scrooge probably hated, prior to his turn-about):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is

> The love of Money is the root of all evil.

Because

> It has heart or love, money, and then a picture of roots, and an evil looking face.

Plus

> Scrooge loved money

Comment: Right on the money, @Quantum!